# Rails : sqlite problem? Deploying from a 32-bit ubuntu to a 64-bit ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, deployment

I've made an application under Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit and am trying to upload it to an Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit server.
I can't get it running, because it's buggin about sqlite:

```
rake aborted!
<my rails dir>/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Apparently, I did something wrong. My guess is the 64-bit is causing problems. Can it be fixed?? and HOW?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to run a 32-bit native (ie, compiled) gem on a 64-bit OS.

Un-vendor your gems and re-install/compile them on your production server.

Comment: Hmm no idea things would be this simple! :D Thanks a lot!
Here's what I did: removed the entire vendor directory (seemed that more gems suffered from this problem) and the .bundle directory, then ran 'bundle install --path vendor'.

Comment: Unless you're developing and deploying on exactly the same platform (or have a nifty automated / managed build and release system), you probably shouldn't have your vendor'd gems in SCM—Bundler makes it that much easier nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

Your path the sqlite3 on your server is incorrect.

```
/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3./lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so:
```

That is what's causing the error. Can you ssh into your server and see what's going on? Try to find out where sqlite3 is and replace the path above with the correct one on your server.

Comment: Oh typo... I corrected it by removing the dot (PuTTy didnt allow me to copy outside PuTTy).
The output comes directly from the server by SSH.

Comment: It's probably because you have different ruby versions on your local and server. Make sure that the ruby versions you are using are the same and that the gems you are using are the same.